# Align Checkbox with Label and Other Input Elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Using Bootstrap 3, I am trying to align adjacent input elements with my label which is intended to be grouped with a checkbox. At the moment, the checkbox and label are displayed a few pixels below the search query box and button. The brand name also appears to be a few pixels higher.

On Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/6tJSBqZ2d5

```
<div class="container row navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
        </div>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="search-form" method="get" name="search-form">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input class="form-control" id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search..." value=""> <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <h3><span class="label label-default">Refresh
                    <input type="checkbox"></span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

What is the proper way to align all elements and have them properly spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h3` is adding `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, and the checkbox element that you have is 8px shorter than the other elements in the header.

So if you add the `h3-align` class as shown below to the `h3` then it will be aligned:

CSS:

```
.h3-align {
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<h3 class="h3-align">
  <span class="label label-default">Refresh
      <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</h3>
```

**[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/L9n4UdQ2FJ)**

Comment: Cool, thanks. How would I make the h3 label the same size as the search button?

Comment: @staticx you could add `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the label as shown here: http://www.bootply.com/UZ7UIuJPBh